# How to run Snakemake workflows on premise Kubernetes or OpenShift clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, workflow, snakemake

We are trying to run Snakemake workflows on Kubernetes on premise infrastructure. We are using OpenShift OKD on a MapR filesystem more precisely.

We followed the [official documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#executing-a-snakemake-workflow-via-kubernetes) command:

```
snakemake --kubernetes --use-conda --default-remote-provider $REMOTE --default-remote-prefix $PREFIX
```

But the command line help provided for `--default-remote-provider` and `--default-remote-prefix` are not clear about how we should execute Snakemake pipelines on a on premise Kubernetes or OpenShift cluster:

```
--default-remote-provider: choose from 'S3', 'GS', 'FTP', 'SFTP', 'S3Mocked', 'gfal', 'gridftp', 'iRODS'
```

Also, the official documentation states:

> In this mode, Snakemake will assume all input and output files to be stored in a given remote location, configured by setting $REMOTE to your provider of choice (e.g. GS for Google cloud storage or S3 for Amazon S3) and $PREFIX to a bucket name or subfolder within that remote storage.

So I was wondering:

- How does one should proceed to deploy Snakemake workflow to on premise OpenShift/Kubernetes installation?
- Is there example (such as github repo or blog) of running Snakemake on premise clusters?
- In particular, I am not sure which remote provider should be chosen, and how to provide the prefix (can it be linked to a Kubernetes Persistent Volume Claim?)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not really familiar with on premise Kubernetes set up, but [this segment of snakemake's documentation on cluster execution may help.](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html)

The portion you've highlighted relates more to cloud implementation of compute clusters.

Comment: Unfortunately that link has died, do you mean https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html?

Comment: @NathanaelFarley, thank you, I've edited the link in my answer as well